# How to retrieve the value of a yield function call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga, redux-middleware

I am working on a project which began last year, and the developers are not with me. They wrote this code :

```
import { put, takeLatest, all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { getUserByUsernameService } from '../../services/userServices';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';

function* fetchUser() {
  const response = yield call(getUserByUsernameService);
  yield put({ type: 'FETCHED_USER', payload: response.data.user });
}

function* actionWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest('FETCHING_USER', fetchUser);
}
export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([actionWatcher()]);
}
```

Code of getUserByUsernameService :

```
import {
  makeGetRequest,
  makePostRequest,
  makePutRequest,
  makeDeleteRequest,
} from '../utils/reqUtils';

export const getUserByUsernameService = (params) => {
  let headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  };
  makeGetRequest('/user', params, headers);
}
```

Code of makeGetRequest :

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const makeGetRequest = (endpoint, params = {}, headers) => {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { ...headers },
    params: params,
    url: endpoint,
  };

  return axiosInstance(options)
    .then((resp) => resp.data)
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      throw e;
    });
};
```

At runtime I get `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` corresponding to the code

`yield put({ type: 'FETCHED_USER', payload: response.data.user });`

So what is wrong ?

Comment: `const response = yield call(getUserByUsernameService);` has resulted as undefined. Are you able to see any request in network tab of browser console?

Comment: yes there is a call to the back-end API , and it has a CORS error

Comment: Hence you are not getting any `response`. So try to get the CORS error resolved from BE, it should resolve your issue as well.

Comment: why is the header I set `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` not considered ?

Comment: Or if you are facing this issue only in development mode then you can fix it with locally for development purpose with this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: Does your BE responds with  the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *? Check if its blocked on BE.

Answer (score 0):

The generator yield returns an object that you can iterate using `next` method.

I think you should use `response.next().valute.data.user`.
I think also as you consume the generator in `fetchUser` you should not yield the result of the `call` API method.

```js
function* fetchUser() {
  const response = call(getUserByUsernameService);
  yield put({ type: 'FETCHED_USER', payload: response.next().value.data.user });
}
```

Comment: now I get `response.next is not a function`

Comment: Probably your function`getUserByUsernameService` is throwing an error so the result of call is `undefined`. To prevent it you can add a check `if (!response) { /* handle error cases */ }` @pheromix

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple typo — you forgot to `return` something from your `getUserByUsernameService` function!  You are calling `makeGetRequest` but not returning the response.  You want

```
return makeGetRequest('/user', params, headers);
```